# Perl way of execute/ignore code (like assert in C)

Tags: perl

I'm a real beginner in Perl programming (v 5.20.2 on Debian 8) and I'm looking to a way of implementing a "debugging" with no overhead at Perl execution-time when I don't need to debug.

In C, we can do that with `assert` and the `-D` gcc option (and in general, you can do your own assert by following the same way with your own define constante like `MY_DEBUG`).

Well, first idea is simply to set a global variable `debug` and test again it, but it will generate a bunch of useless test when I will don't want to be in debug mode.

There are CPAN Module like [assertions](https://metacpan.org/pod/assertions) or [Carp::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert), but it's seem that there will be an if test even when I don't want debugging.

Is there a Perl way for deactivate portion of code depending on "something"?

Bonus question: I want to make a Perl module with the same functionality, so if there is a way to say "enable/disable debugging" when I do the `use MyModule`, well, I will be a happy Perl developer.

Comment: The only practical way I can think of is using a source filter. But why are you so eager to avoid any possible overhead from disabled debugging code? Is your code already impractically slow and you can't afford to make it any worse?

Comment: Well, I write a little parser for a csv-like file, and the file is over 40Go and it take like 24 hours to complete, so if I can develop something with no overhead, I will be happy. It's the most recent example, but I will have to write more Perl script in a soon futur, so I better be prepared.

Comment: I guess you mean 40 Gigabyte. If that's a one-time program, it doesn't really matter. If you need to run this a lot, you can post it on codereview.se and we can take a look. In that case, you might want to do some Devel::NYTProf, but remember that the first rule of profiling is _don't do it_. If you also have a database involved, read the documentation for DBI's profiler.

Comment: It's the first rule of optimization not profiling.

Comment: `assert()` in C is special not because of the `#ifndef NDEBUG`; instead it can output the original expression to test without variable substitution (if you write `assert (a < b)` your **do not** get `3 < 4` (for example) or even `0` as output.). That's the hard part in Perl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl does not have that built-in. There is also no compiling happening like in C because Perl is an interpreted language. The fact that [Carp::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert) exists (and is written by someone who is involved in the Perl core) is a pretty good assertion (pun intended) that this feature is not there in Perl directly.

In general, a couple of `if DEBUG` or `if $debug` or similar are no big deal. Computers today are so fast that those operations hardly matter unless you have them in a loop that gets called millions of times, or you have extremely time-critical code. In your average program, you can ignore that overhead.

In fact perl<sup>1</sup> will optimize those out if you use a constant. Consider this program.

```
use constant DEBUG => 1;
print "stuff" if DEBUG;
```

If run with [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse), it will produce the following output.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse scratch.pl 
use constant ('DEBUG', 1);
print 'stuff';
scratch.pl syntax OK
```

There's our `print` statement. But if you turn the `DEBUG` constant to `0` and run the same command, you get something else.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse scratch.pl 
use constant ('DEBUG', 0);
'???';
scratch.pl syntax OK
```

As you can see, the `print` is gone. All that remains is `'???';`, which is a NOOP.

Let's run the same thing with [B::Concise](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html). First, with `DEBUG` turned to `0`.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise scratch.pl 
3  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 120 scratch.pl:1129) v:{ ->3
-     <0> ex-const v*/4,FOLD ->3
scratch.pl syntax OK
```

And then with `DEBUG` set to `1`.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise scratch.pl 
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 120 scratch.pl:1129) v:{ ->3
5     <@> print vK/FOLD ->6
3        <0> pushmark s ->4
4        <$> const(PV "stuff") s ->5
scratch.pl syntax OK
```

As you can see, there are more operations. The `print "stuff" if DEBUG` is in fact optimized out. This is pretty much the same thing as what you describe in your C example.

Go ahead and try out with those two modules to see if it behaves the same when using [Carp::Assert](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp::Assert).

---

If you don't like that, take a look at [Smart::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Smart::Comments). It introduces comment syntax that get executed when you `use` it. That's pretty cool, because those can just sit around and not do stuff when you don't load the module.

> ```
> use Smart::Comments;
>
> my $var = suspect_value();
>
> ### $var
> ```

There is also [Devel::Comments](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Comments), which seems to do the same.

<sup>1) *perl* with a small p is the interpreter program, not the language</sup>

Comment: Big thanks to you. I will take time to read and experiment all of this, especially if I can easely use that in a Perl Module.

Comment: I'm wondering why the `DEBUG` constant itself isn't optimized out. I mean: It's used, but all uses have been optimized in a way that it's not needed any more. If either all debug prints are removed, or all debug prints are executed, there is no reason to keep `DEBUG` itself...

Comment: @U.Windl that's because the constant is really a function. And while the Perl compiler optimizes things away that are never called, functions could be called dynamically, so it won't remove them